# How can I simplify this expression further?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, inequality, systems-of-equations

The problem:
Two points are being chosen from $[0,1]$. These points create 3 sections x,y,z. Show the sample space using x,y.

How could I simplify this expression even further?
And is it correct what I've done till now?

$\begin{array}{l}
\Omega =\ \{< x,\ y,\ z> \ |\ 0\leqslant x< y< z< 1\ |\ x+y+z\ =\ 1\}\\
=\ \ \{< x,\ y,\ z> \ |\ 0\leqslant x< y< z< 1\ |\ z\ =\ 1-x-y\}\\
=\ \ \ \{< x,\ y> \ |\ 0\leqslant x< y< 1-x-y< 1\}
\end{array}$

EDIT:

I just realized that the "smaller than one" in the first expression is probably reductant. I mean, given they are all positive, different, and add up to 1, how could they be bigger or equal to one?

So now it looks like this:
\begin{array}{l}
\Omega\ =\ \{< x,\ y,\ z> \ |\ 0\leqslant x< y< z\ |\ x+y+z\ =\ 1\}\\
=\ \{< x,\ y,\ z> \ |\ 0\leqslant x< y< z\ |\ z\ =\ 1-x-y\}\\
=\ \{< x,\ y> \ |\ 0\leqslant x< y< 1-x-y\}\\
=\ \{< x,\ y> \ |\ 0\leqslant x< y< 1-x-y\}
\end{array}

Or is this more correct?

$\begin{array}{l}
\Omega =\ \{< x,\ y,\ z> \ |\ 0\leqslant x< y< z\ |\ x+y+z\ =\ 1\}\\
=\ \ \{< x,\ y,\ z> \ |\ 0\leqslant x< y< z\ |\ z\ =\ 1-x-y\}\\
=\ \ \ \{< x,\ y,\ 1-x-y> \ |\ 0\leqslant x< y< 1-x-y\}
\end{array}$

Thanks

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi I edit it. Does it change something in your comment?

Comment: After your edit, the three sets are indeed equal. But none of them can really be said to be much simpler than the original.  Maybe this is being done in the service of solving a different problem, and you should mention what that problem is?  Right now it's looking like you're agonizing over something nobody would really care to do.

Comment: @rschwieb I edited and added the original probelm